# broken table in downloadable product tab

Tags: downloadable, table

The table that is to be shown in downloadable product tab does not show the link and the availability and download numbers. Does any body have a solution? I use a Venus theme in RTL Persian language.

[image]

I shall say that the page source give this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error is in `Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download')`. Check downloadable helper (try `var_dump(Mage::helper('downloadable'))`) and if it returns `false` look if it had not been rewritten by some module

Comment: thanks,
I get the link in the email and it downloads the document but in the table there is a problelem.

Comment: Also the error repeats in this case

Comment: using your suggestion , it appears so:  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FsB7P.png

Comment: And what `var_dump(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('test'))` returns?

Comment: no change, the table is broken but the error message is shown in the table and when I click on it, it opens the downloadable document. @vasyl Malanka